# PHP Variables Not Displaying in Browser

Tags: php, variables, echo, associative-array

I have the following function:

```
function getAllProducts($productCount) {
$productsParsed = 0;
$limit = 250;
$pages = ceil($productCount / $limit);
$pageNumber = 1;
$filters = "";
$requestParams = array("page" => $pageNumber, "limit" => $limit, "include" => $filters);

echo $productCount . " products to parse... \n";
echo "=======================================\n";

if ($productCount <= $limit) {
    $products = Bigcommerce::getProducts($requestParams);
    $products = (array) $products;

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $productsParsed++;
        echo $product -> name . "   " . $product -> price . "\n";
    }
} else { // More than $limit products in catalog.
    while ($productsParsed <= $productCount) {
        if ($productsParsed === 0 || $productsParsed % $limit > 0) {
            // 0 or not on a multiple of $limit
            $products = Bigcommerce::getProducts($requestParams);
            $productsObject = new ArrayObject($products);
            $productsArray = $productsObject->getArrayCopy();

            foreach ($productsArray as $product) {
                $productsParsed++;
                echo $product -> name . "   " . $product -> price . "\n";
            }
        } else {
            // multiple of $limit
            $pageNumber++;
            $requestParams = array("page" => $pageNumber, "limit" => $limit, "include" => $filters);
            $products = Bigcommerce::getProducts($requestParams);
            $productsObject = new ArrayObject($products);
            $productsArray = $productsObject->getArrayCopy();

            foreach ($productsArray as $product) {
                $productsParsed++;
                echo $product -> name . "   " . $product -> price . "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
if ($productsParsed == $productCount) {
    echo "=======================================\n All products accounted for.\n";
} else {
    $missingProducts = $productCount - $productsParsed;
    echo "=======================================\n" . $missingProducts . " products unaccounted for.\n";
}
}
```

When I run the script at the command line everything performs as expected, I get a correct product count, as well as the output from the `$product` variable, however in the browser none of the variables echo back, so I end up with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

 products to parse... 
=======================================
=======================================
 All products accounted for.

</body>
</html>
```

What could cause this to echo back differently between the terminal and the browser?

Comment: With the calls to `Bigcommerce`, it is not feasible for anyone else to actually run your code. What have you done to attempt to debug your difference in output?

Comment: @jbafford, I just did a var_dump() on $productCount.  At the command line, it comes back as int(152), however in the browser it comes back NULL.  I really have a hard time understanding that, because both are on a local server, its not like I'm using a command line locally but a remote server for the browser view.

Comment: If productCount is null, one would assume you aren't passing a parameter to the call to getAllProducts in your web php file.

Comment: Add this line to line 9 above : if (!empty($productCount) {echo $productCount . " products to parse... \n"; } else { echo "No products"; }

Comment: Thanks @crafter, thats the thing; the browser sees it as empty, the command line recognizes the value (152).

Comment: Then you should look next at what value you are passing into the function getAllProducts(). So it appears the issue is with the value passed. You have not shown this code, so it is difficult to see where the value is coming from and why it not being set to your expected value.